# Ajuda para preencher jTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

Estou preenchendo uma jtable com os aniversariantes que estão cadastrados em um banco de dados.

```
  public void jTablePop()
{
    javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel dtm2 = (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();  
    dtm2.setNumRows(0);  
    //ISSO TIRA AS LINHAS DA TABELA  
    int x=0;

    try{
    conexao.Conectar();

    conexao.sql = "select cli_nome,cli_cpf,cli_data_nascimento from contrato where  id_cli > 1 ";
    conexao.ps = conexao.con.prepareStatement(conexao.sql);
    conexao.rs = conexao.ps.executeQuery();

    while(conexao.rs.next())
    {
        //codigo
        dtm2.addRow(new Object[]{" ","  "," "}); 
        jTable1.setValueAt(conexao.rs.getString(1),x,0);  
        jTable1.setValueAt(conexao.rs.getString(2),x,1);  
        jTable1.setValueAt(conexao.rs.getString(3),x,2); 
        x++;
    }


    }catch(SQLException ex){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ex.getMessage(), "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       }
}
```

Porém eu preciso que na jTable apareça só os aniversariantes do mês, como eu poderia fazer isto ? ja consegui colocar a data em uma variavel deste modo :

```
public void kappa()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
        Date y=new Date(); 
        String keppo = sdf1.format(y).toString();

    }
```

Como poderia fazer para exibir na jTable apenas os aniversariantes do mês ? poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Primeiro pega o mês atual utilizando a biblioteca Calendar, depois tu converte tua data de nascimento em Calendar e pega só o mês também. Por fim faz um if dentro desse while que verifica se os meses são iguais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer deste modo, se alguém que estiver lendo isso tiver a mesma duvida. Eis a solução :

```
 public void jTablePop()
    {

        javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel dtm2 = (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();  
        dtm2.setNumRows(0);  

        int x=0;

        try{

        conexao.Conectar();
        Calendar c1= Calendar.getInstance();
        String hora1 = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+(c1.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
        se.setText(hora1);

        conexao.sql = "SELECT cli_nome,tel,cli_data_nascimento FROM contrato WHERE LEFT(cli_data_nascimento,5) =?";
        conexao.ps = conexao.con.prepareStatement(conexao.sql);
        conexao.ps.setString(1,se.getText());
        conexao.rs = conexao.ps.executeQuery();

        while(conexao.rs.next())
        {
            //codigo
            dtm2.addRow(new Object[]{" ","  "," "}); 
            jTable1.setValueAt(conexao.rs.getString(1),x,0);  
            jTable1.setValueAt(conexao.rs.getString(2),x,1);  
            jTable1.setValueAt(conexao.rs.getString(3),x,2); 
            x++;
        }

        }catch(SQLException ex){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, ex.getMessage(), "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           }
    }
```